# Check if the previous value is present in the dataset with a logical operation [R]

Tags: r, logical-operators

I have this dataset

```
structure(list(N = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "a", "b", "c", 
"a", "c"), S = c("4", "4", "4", "3", "3", "2", "2", "2", "1", 
"1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

And I would like to verify if all group 'N' have a previous observation 'S'. And that with a logical operation

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% group_by(N) %>% arrange(desc(S)) %>% mutate(L = ifelse(****))
```

The output should looks like this

| N | S | P |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 4 | TRUE |
| b | 4 | TRUE |
| c | 4 | FALSE |
| a | 3 | TRUE |
| b | 3 | TRUE |
| a | 2 | TRUE |
| b | 2 | FALSE |
| c | 2 | TRUE |
| a | 1 | FALSE |
| c | 1 | FALSE |

Comment: Could you please explain the logic again?

Comment: The idea is to group the dataframe by 'N', and after check for each 'N' value if there is a lower 'S'. If a lower value of 'S' is present, the output will be TRUE (e.g.: a-3). If a lower value is not present, the output will be FALSE (e.g.: c-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this - it sorts by `S` within group and then identifies the first (smallest value of `S`) as `FALSE` and the others as `TRUE` if they equal the lag of `S` plus one.

```r
library(dplyr)
dat <- structure(list(N = c("a", "b", "a", "b", "c", "a", "c"), 
                      S = c("4", "3", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-7L))

dat %>% 
  mutate(S = as.numeric(S)) %>% 
  group_by(N) %>% 
  arrange(S, .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(P= S == (lag(S)+1), 
         P = ifelse(is.na(P), FALSE, P))
#> # A tibble: 7 × 3
#> # Groups:   N [3]
#>   N         S P    
#>   <chr> <dbl> <lgl>
#> 1 a         1 FALSE
#> 2 a         2 TRUE 
#> 3 a         4 FALSE
#> 4 b         2 FALSE
#> 5 b         3 TRUE 
#> 6 c         1 FALSE
#> 7 c         2 TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I thought the code worked properly, but I realized there is still a problem if there is a gap within one of the group. I have updated my data frame to help to visualize the issue.

Comment: Apologies, @C.Guff, I edited the answer to something that should work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

We may use the `lead` to get the difference with the adjacent elements, convert the difference to logical vector (`==`), grouped by N

```
library(dplyr)# version >= 1.1.0
df %>% 
 type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(P =  (S - lead(S, default = last(S)) == 1), .by = N)
```

-output

```
    N S     P
1  a 4  TRUE
2  b 4  TRUE
3  c 4 FALSE
4  a 3  TRUE
5  b 3  TRUE
6  a 2  TRUE
7  b 2 FALSE
8  c 2  TRUE
9  a 1 FALSE
10 c 1 FALSE
```

Comment: It works in that example, but if I had for example a b-0 or a c-4, it is not working. It has to see if the previous value is present and not just a lower one

Comment: @C.Guff Sorry, your logic was not clear to me.  when it is c4, are you considering the oriiginal order of the values or not.  In the other post, it is arranging the data

Comment: For c-4 means N = "c" and S = 4. For b-0 it's N = "b" and S = 0. Both of these observations are not present in the dataset I provided

Comment: @C.Guff Can you please update your post with a new example as the criteria will be more readable in that way. thanks

Comment: The dataset have been updated @akrun

Comment: @C.Guff can you try the updated code

Comment: I have a different output than yours... The row 4 & 6 (a-3 & a-2) are False instead of being TRUE. And that with the same dataframe than my example. (I have updated my dplyr, just to be sure)

Comment: @C.Guff that is strange as I tried it again on a fresh R session and getting the same output as i got